# Exported Model and Shader Not Displaying as Intended

Tags: modeling, export, shaders, glass

I used Blender 2.79 to create this model and shader in cycles render
[image]

I exported it as a .obj & then attempted to display it in **a-frame** and I get the following result
[image]

I would like to know how I can get the same glassy shader on the exported model

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Cycles is a blender specific feature and any shader you make in a .blend file wont really transfer to say an .obj or any other exported file form.

For what I know, .obj's consist of a mesh and a texture and can't display such a complicated shader as a refractive, ray-traced glass.

Comment: Basically, you can't expect to have the same result between two different render engines. Even Cycles and EEVEE, being made to work together, don't get the same result.